# Missing return statements, loops

Tags: java, loops, if-statement, return

A method I'm using requires loops, and I have managed to work myself into a corner trying to split up the loops up by adding new methods. I've pasted part of my code below.
I'm currently receiving the error message "missing return statement" and although I realise why this is happening I am unsure as how to continue. Any help or suggestions would be appreciated! Thanks.

```
public String addJob(String cust,boolean onSite, boolean sHand, String lang)
 {   int nt = 100;

    if (customers.containsKey(cust))
    {
             if (0 >= getCustomerCredit(cust)) { 
             return " Customer over credit limit "; }

             if (nt >= getCustomerCredit(cust))
             {
                Job jb = new Job(cust, onSite, sHand, lang);
                job.put(jb, getNewJobNo());
                    if(lang != "English")
                      { 
                        isStaffAvailableWork(trnsltr);}
                    if(sHand == false)
                      { isStaffAvailableWork(clk);
                      }
                    else { isStaffAvailableWork(typst);
                      }

            }

    }
     else { 
           Customer c = new Customer(cust);
           customers.put(cust, ntnt);
           Job jb = new Job(cust, onSite, sHand, lang);
           job.put(jb, getNewJobNo());
                if(lang != "English")
                  { 
                    isStaffAvailableWork(trnsltr);}
                if(sHand == false)
                  { isStaffAvailableWork(clk);
                  }
                else { isStaffAvailableWork(typst);
                      }

    }    
 }

 public String isStaffAvailableWork(Staff stf)
 {    
      if (staff.containsKey(stf)&&(stf.isStaffAvailable()==true))
      { 
           jb.setJobStatusOnGoing();
           stf.setStaffBusy();
           jobNoAndstaffId.put(staff.get(stf), job.get(jb));
           return "Staff allocated: " + stf;

       }

      if (staff.containsKey(stf)&&(stf.isStaffAvailable()==false))
      { 
           jb.setJobStatusWaiting(); 
           return "Job Waiting";

       }
      else return null;
    }
```

Comment: You need explicit return(s). `return isStaffAvailableWork`. Also, that isn't how you compare `String`(s).

Comment: I'm confused by the reference to loops.

Comment: To help you understand what Elliott said... Use `!lang.equals("English")` instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question is somewhat broad, but your issue is that your function somehow isn't giving back a value. Every line from which a function can exit must return something.

```
public bool foo(var x)
{
    if(x == 0)
    {
        // Returns successfully.
        return true;
    }
    else if(x != 0)
    {
        // Didn't return anything.
    }
    // Also didn't return anything.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Elliott Frisch answered this in a comment.

The problem is that your `addJob` doesn't return anything.

Where you have things like:

```
isStaffAvailableWork(trnsltr);
```

you need

```
return isStaffAvailableWork(trnsltr);
```

As it stands, that method isn't returning anything so your compiler is saying so.